# How to make Spring Boot Reactive endpoints visible to SpringDoc OpenApi

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-webflux, openapi, springfox

I am working on a new Spring Boot reactive server application.  The application exposes reactive endpoints as shown below:

```
@Configuration
public class XXXXRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes(ClaimsHandler handler) {
        return nest(path("/api/xxxx"), nestedRoutes(handler));
    }

    private static RouterFunction<ServerResponse> nestedRoutes(xxxxHandler handler) {
        return route(GET("/"), handler::allClaims)
            .andRoute(GET("/{id}"), handler::byId)
            .andRoute(GET("/{id}/notes"), handler::notesById);
    }

}
```

I need to make these endpoints to swagger-ui like framework.  I am using following dependencies to generate required swagger-ui and api-docs:

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-core:1.2.32'
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.2.32'
```

I also have the following API config:

```
@Configuration
public class OpenAPIConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI().components(new Components()).info(new Info().title("Contact Application API")
                .description("This is a sample Spring Boot RESTful service using springdoc-openapi and OpenAPI 3."));
    }

}
```

localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html shows swagger-ui page.  But, endpoints are not shown there.

Here is the output from localhost:8080/v3/api-docs:

```
{"openapi":"3.0.1","info":{"title":"Contact Application API","description":"This is a sample Spring Boot RESTful service using springdoc-openapi and OpenAPI 3."},"servers":[{"url":"http://localhost:8080","description":"Generated server url"}],"paths":{},"components":{}}
```

My question is how do we make the reactive endpoints available to swagger-ui.html?

Comment: I recommend using Spring Rest Docs (https://spring.io/projects/spring-restdocs). It's a tool that the Spring team created for own docs. Swagger is too complex and overhhead with cofigs